# product gallery.css missing magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

The product gallery seems to be broken and it says that gallery.css is missing. Where should this file be in the site structure. Any ideas how it might of gone walkies?

[image: Gallery page css error]

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem of *css* and *js* page load design after installation in Magento 2, please follow the following step:

1. Open the terminal and navigate to magento web root:

   ```
   $ cd /var/www/html/magento2
   ```
2. Deploy static content:

   ```
   $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
3. Make reindex:

   ```
   $ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
4. Make sure apache `rewrite_module` is enable and then restart the server.
5. Set file system ownership:

   ```
   $ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
   ```
6. and permissions:

   ```
   $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
   ```
7. Delete cache folder under `var/cache`

The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.

Let me know if any issue. :)

[Source.](http://gotechnies.com/css-javascript-files-loading-magento-2-installation/)

Comment: Completed that list but gallery.css still fails to load?

Comment: @Mark can you please add screenshot to the question

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Any ideas as to what the problem might be?